# Dynamic html in mandrill template email

Tags: mandrill

I am trying to add dynamic html table string in div with mc:edit but it is not rendered as html it only display that string in email.

div tag in template:

```
<div mc:edit="tracker"> 
</div>
```

my html string:

```
 <table border='1px' cellspacing='1px'>
   <tr>
      <table border=1px cellspacing=1px>
         Test</tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <table border=1px cellspacing=1px>
         Walk</tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
            <td class=class1></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And if i paste this string directly in template it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strHTML). I removed that and simply passed strHTML & it is working now.